# How to launch a dependent application on OS X?

Tags: macos, launching-application

What is the programmatical mechanism by which an application can be launched at a result of another one being launched?

E.g. upon launching iTunes, the Last.fm desktop launches too.

Or it is just a question of substituting a "batch file" of some sort?

**Note:** OS X newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard way to specify a dependent app. So, you need to somehow watch the system. You don't have to actively poll; you need to use some system mechanism to tell you.

To watch for a GUI app to launch, you need to write a background app, get the NSWorkspace's notification center by

```
NSNotificationCenter* nc=[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
```

and watch for NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification. See the [`Apple doc`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCICJJEJ).

To watch for a non-GUI app to launch, you need to use `kqueue`. (This is a BSD feature.) See the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html). Typically you have to watch `launchd` to `fork` or `execve` processes. Note that there are multiple `launchd` processes, one for root and one for each logged-in users.

In any case you need to start automatically the background app you write.  There're many ways to do that.

To watch a file or a directory to change, you can use `launchd` agents. See the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html).

By the way: the official `Last.fm` app, on its first launch, installs `AudioScrobbler.bundle` inside `~/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins`. iTunes reads all the plug-ins when launched, and the plug-in then launches the Last.fm app. It's a rather hackish, non-condoned usage of the interface, because the plug-in is for the visualizer. See [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn/tn2016.html).

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do this from the man page you are referring to.  Could you expand on this one?

But +1 for the "last.fm" rundown!

Comment: Ah, sorry for putting confusion information... `launchd` agents can watch for the appearance of new files in a directory, but it can't watch for the launching of a new app. You can use `kqueue`, but that's not an elegant way... I'll add the info on kqueue.